# Sending Flask variable from HTML back to Flask with url_for()

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to create a little job board, each job card is dynamically inserted from flask from a list (for now, will be an SQL DB later)

[image: Screenshot]

When the user clicks the button `View Task` I want it to go to another page where it displays the task/job in more detail.

What I want attached to that button is the job/task ID.

This is how I'd want/expect the button to function

```
{% for task in available_tasks %}
<div>
   <a href="{{ url_for('view_task', task_id={{ task['id'] }}) }}">View Task</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This could then be pasted into a route that would take the ID as an argument and fetch the full job/task information.

```
app.route('/view_task/<task_id>')
def view_task(task_id):
   task_data = task_database[taskid]
   return render_template('detailed_view.html', task_info=task_data)
```

My problem is `href="url_for('view_task', task_id={{ task['id'] }})"` doesn't work, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's how it normally is done. I'm not sure what you are asking; a *better way to send back dynamic data* is *hugely* broad.

Comment: Its not working though? `href="url_for('view_task', task_id={{ task['id'] }})"` it doesn't recognize the arguement. I could do `task_id='1'` doesnt seem to like the jinja {{ }}

Comment: Ah, yes, you got the syntax mixed up a little. **But you didn't tell us that you had an error**. Please show the full error message, with traceback if possible, for problems.

Comment: And since you don't have an error here, but just incorrect output, it'd have been helpful if you had shown that instead. Do look at the HTML that Flask returns to the browser, not just what the browser has rendered as a result. You'd have seen the `href="..."` value was a bit off, not containing an actual URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generated the output `href="url_for('view_task', task_id=<some id>)"`, so the literal text `url_for(..)` is in the HTML generated and delivered to your browser, and HTML engines don't recognise that string as a valid URL for anything.

You need to put the `url_for()` function in the `{{ ... }}` brackets, not just the task id value:

```html
href="{{ url_for('view_task', task_id=task['id']) }}"
```

Only then is `url_for()` actually treated as an expression for Jinja2 to execute, at which point the HTML produces will contain the `href="http://localhost:5000/view_task/<some id>"` string.