# How to correctly send variables to Flask Route using url_for()?

Tags: python, flask

I have seen a couple of other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549923/sending-flask-variable-from-html-back-to-flask-with-url-for) asking for ways to send variables from HTML back to flask using url_for() and so I tried it too.

```html
{% for movie in movies %}
       <article class="media content-section">
         <div class="media-body">
           <div class="article-metadata">
             <h3><a class="mr-2 mt-4" href="{{url_for('movies', movie_id=movie.id)}}" method="POST">{{ movie.title }}</a></h3>
             <small class="text-muted">{{ movie.year }}</small>
             <small class="text-muted">ID : {{ movie.id }}</small>
           </div>
           <h6><a class="article-title">Rating : {{ movie.rating }}</a></h6>
         </div>
       </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

As seen in line 5, I did a url_for() and sent a variable called movie_id which was the id attribute of my movie object to my route which looked like this,

```py
@app.route('/movies/<movie_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def movies(movie_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        movie = Movie.query.filter_by(id=movie_id).first()
    return render_template('movies.html', movie=movie)
```

However, upon running the code, I get the error saying that `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'movie' referenced before assignment`. This occurs at the last line of my route `return render_template('movies.html', movie=movie)`. May I know where I went wrong?

Comment: Why are you sending `movie.id` back? Do you just want to list all the movies?

Comment: @WytammaWirth On this page, I have evey movie in my database in a blog post style where the user can choose to click on anyone based on the title. So when the user clicks on the title, I want to send that movie id to the movie route where I can display all the info about that movie. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only querying for the movie if the request method is 'POST'

Perhaps you got an error because you were calling the route with a 'GET' method instead. This would typically be the case if you're just accessing the URL directly from the browser (without using forms etc).

Try removing that `if` statement

Comment: Ah it works now. But do you mind explaining why its a GET request when I'm sending information? I'm very new to flask sorry.

Comment: The default method of an anchor tag with pure HTML is GET.  Without JavaScript to do something fancy like: on-click submit hidden form with POST.  Setting method=POST in an anchor tag essentially does nothing!